# UFT API Testing: timeStamp using C#

Tags: c#, uft-api

I have a requirement to parameter the time stamp in my SOAP Request below. 
I'm planning to write custom code in C# for the same.

Could you please help on the same.

```
<timeStamp>2017-11-11T03:52:26.464-06:00</timeStamp>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to check and transoform the XML value to something in C# this is would work:

```
var input = "2017-11-10T16:46:55.711-06:00";
var ok = DateTimeOffset.TryParse(input, out var parsed);
Console.WriteLine(ok ? parsed.ToString() : "Invalid");
```

and to write it back formatted:

```
Console.WriteLine(parsed.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy\\THH:mm:ss zzz"));
```

Comment: I need the c# code to get the time stamp in the format of '2017-11-11T03:52:26.464-06:00'